# How to write double Ajax request on pure js and then return a common value?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like get a result that will allow me to download the data of two movies from the database omdbapi.com. Next compare for example the actors and returns common actors of these films.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
movie_serch.addEventListener("click", movieSerch, false);

function movieSerch(){
movieA = document.getElementById("userInput").value,
movieB = document.getElementById("userInput2").value;

requestFirst = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestFirst.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+movieA+'&y=&plot=short&r=json', true);

requestSecound = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestSecound.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+movieB+'&y=&plot=short&r=json', true);

requestFirst.onload = function() {
  if (requestFirst.status >= 200 && requestFirst.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var respFirst = JSON.parse(this.responseText),
    actors = respFirst.Actors.split(", "),
        director = respFirst.Director.split(", ");
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
}; 
requestSecound.onload = function() {
   if (requestSecound.status >= 200 && requestSecound.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var respSecound = JSON.parse(requestSecound.responseText);
    actors = respSecound.Actors.split(", "),
    director = respSecound.Director.split(", ");
    } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
  }
};
requestFirst.send();
requestSecound.send();
};
```

Comment: Are you happy to use Promises?

Comment: By "pure js", do you mean regular, 'ol vanilla JavaScript, or are you referring to one of the Pure.js libraries that are available?

Comment: So, what is your question/problem? your current code seems to be OK. what about the comparison part?

Comment: I do not know how to begin the comparison part this is a problem.

Comment: I mean regular JS without libraries like jQuery.

Comment: as @JaromandaX suggested, please do some research on `JavaScript promises`. then you can compare two arrays with normal loops...

Comment: Promises make tidy code, but you can do it without them very easily as well